# Widening cabinets to fit a OTR microwave

Tags: kitchens

Purchased an older home with odd custom kitchen cabinets. I am wanting to remove the ugly box range vent and add a box shelf and an OTR microwave, but the width between my side cabinets is 28 inches.  How big of a problem is it to move these cabinets over to increase the width.

[image]

Comment: It depends how they are fastened to the wall, whether you can move them in sections, is there space at the far end for them to move into, etc. etc. etc. Pictures might help us better advise you.

Comment: You may also need to look at how it would affect trim like crown molding and the backsplash.

Comment: Pictures would tell us how easy/hard it would be to create a 30" cabinet to match your existing cabs. (Or if you could somehow magically gain 1" on each side.) If this is a short-term fix, then LG makes a 22" OTR unit. (LMV1314)

Comment: What do you intend to fill the gap above the microwave with? Almost any range hood microwave requires top-mount support.

Answer (score 1):

Picture(s) would help for your "move these cabinets over" statement. But, if you have room then it's just unscrew from each other & from studs...in that order. To then re-mount them to other studs & back to each other.

However, you may also be able to swap cabinets to get a few more inches. If you have cabinets on other walls there may be a thinner one in an area that can accept the fatter one.